# 'gradle test' stops working after parametrizing build.gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jooq, flyway

I have a spring boot application and some integration tests using `@SpringBootTest` annotation. The tests insert and delete some data into/from the database.
There are also **jOOQ** code generation and **Flyway** migration tasks in the `build.gradle`

All the db parameters like `url, user, password` are hard-coded in both the tasks.

```
...

flyway {
   ...
   url = ...
   ...
}
    
jooq {
   ...
   url =
   ...
}
    
generateJooq.dependsOn('flywayMigrate')

...
```

The below commands are executed successfully:

```
gradle clean build
gradle test
```

But as I don't want to duplicate DB parameters across the `build.gradle` I've decided to read them from `application.yml`. For that purpose I've added a task:

```
task config {
    ...
            project.ext."dbUrl" = dataSource.get("url");
            project.ext."dbUserName" = dataSource.get("username");
            project.ext."dbPassword" = dataSource.get("password");
            project.ext."dbSchema" = dataSource.get("schema");
    ...
}
```

and changed **Flyway** and **jOOQ** tasks to read them:

```
flyway {
   ...
   url = project.ext."dbUrl"
   ...
}
```

However when I run:

```
gradle clean build
```

the test fails with the error:

```
my.pack.LoaderApplicationTest > whenValidDh_then70Records FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:798
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:798
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:798
                    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:798
                        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603
                            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796
                                Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.InvalidConfigurationPropertyValueException at DataSourceInitializer.java:163
```

It looks like Spring isn't able to initialize the datasource, but I don't understand how it should be related to the added parameters in the `build.gradle`.

The build without test runs without errors: `gradle clean build -x test`

How should I change `build.gradle` so that `gradle test` continues to run successfully after adding those DB parameters?